# jQuery.load() returns an XML error when loading script in loaded html snippet

Tags: jquery

I have the following in my `index.html`:

```
  <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/setContent.js"></script>

  <div id="includeHeader"></div>
```

where in my `setContent.js` replaces the `includeHeader` with the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#includeHeader").load("html/header.html");
});
```

Now in my `header.html` there is another scirpt tag that gets loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="js/header.js"></script>
```

Now I get the following error:

> `js/header.js`: XML not well formed

This is running locally (`file:///C:/index.html`) within Firefox(up to date).

Is there a way to solve that? Do I somehow to tell that this is not an XML file? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Load your page from a localhost server not `file://` protocol

Comment: Is that really the whole error message? It shouldn't be trying to parse `header.js` as XML.

Comment: You shouldn't have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in a file that's intended to be loaded into a DIV. That only belongs at the beginning of a top-level HTML file.